# Emulate physical click in Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

I am trying to programmatically trigger a click on a wordpress page on a <a href="#"... tag which after clicked shows a div with all categories... (the div is not hidden it gets created after clicking the button)
When trying to find the click event behind this element on chrome debugger DOM in event listeners the only event attached
to this element is flatsome.js?ver=3.12.1:109
the handler is f(t) ............
using jQuery Audit, I can see the handler definition, then there are many functions like !function(t)... because it is minified.

I tried to use jQuery click, mouseup, mousedown events (also with trigger('click...') ) with no success, it gets the object, doesn't show an error, but never shows the filter menu.

Is there a way to just emulate the physical click as if it was done with the mouse? then I wouldn't need to call the function, I can't seem to find what function is behind the click event...

Thank you in advance
Dario

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following code?

Using jQuery:

```
$('your-query-selector').trigger('click');
```

Using JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('your-query-selector').click();
```

Comment: Yes, all combinations available in stack overflow (or at least what I found)...

Comment: I know that the jQuery Description for trigger() is : Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type. But it doesnt seem to be working...